# I would like to reposition a circle created through Raphael js, and to use it as a letter in a title

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael, vector-graphics

I have created a vector graphic using Raphael JS - specifically a circle.

I would now like to use this circle as the letter "O" in a title. It is also a circle that will animate upon click. I would like to know if this is at all possible.

Here is a fiddle to explain better what I'm trying to say.

The html is very simple:

```
<h2>N<span id="canvas_cont"></span>OTRE APPROCHE :</h2>
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXtqb/1/)

Basically the circle will act as the second letter in "Notre", and when clicked will move to the right of the screen. Other things will happen after, but this effect is what I'm trying to get....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing the Raphael canvas in a span is clever, but at the end of the day I suspect you'll regret mixing native HTML with Raphael in this way. Doing so would probably require a lot of absolute positioning and z-indexes that are better handled and supported in Raphael.

I recommend you simple draw the text in Raphael:

```
var text = r.set();
text.push(
    r.text(10,20,"N"),
    r.text(70,20,"TRE APPROCHE :")
);
text.attr({
    'text-anchor': 'start',
    'font-size':'36px'        
});
```

If the SVG/VML styling is inadequate, you could also just use an image. Again, I would recommend placing that image on the canvas using Raphael (paper.image());

Note that, in the updated fiddle, I made the canvas a div the width of the logo.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXtqb/2/).

Comment: thank you - seems to work great - just changed the x position when rolling back so that it takes up initial position. thank you!

Comment: That will make your animation easier to accomplish if it goes outside of its original bounding box, as well.  I use a similar technique (but using print) on my site, voidblossom.com, so that the entire header is composed of separately animated glyphs.

Comment: ah thanks, accepted now. forgive the newbie :-) y'all are very helpful around here